# How to load UltiSnips file types by default in JS files?

Tags: javascript, vim, code-snippets, ultisnips

I know that doing `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes javascript-node` in vim console works. But I need this load automatically whenever I open a javascript file. Regardless documentation, I understood that I should create a **ftplugin/javascript.vim** file and put `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes javascript-node` in first line. The thing is those snippets are not loaded.

So, how can make this works please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `autocmd` in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType javascript UltiSnipsAddFiletypes javascript-node
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on to @tckmn 's answer, I used this for multiple filetypes, keeping in mind that `UltiSnipsAddFiletypes` uses `.` as a delimiter:

```
autocmd FileType javascript,javascriptreact,typescript,typescriptreact
  \ UltiSnipsAddFiletypes javascript.javascriptreact.typescript.typescriptreact
```